# Does Azure Web Jobs and Azure App Service API read from the same "Application Settings" once deployed?

Tags: azure

I am hosting an API with Azure App Services and there is also a Web Job deployed. When I debug locally, I have to have the app settings config keys in the web.config and the app.config respectively for each project. On the azure app portal, there is a place to add 'Application Settings' - I am wondering if once deployed and running, will both the API and WebJob read from this same location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your solution is deployed into azure, all projects within it will first read the app settings that were saved onto the azure portal. These settings will override local settings.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation i read came from this blog post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/

Basically, both web job and API first look for any setting in the application settings section. If that value exists, they take it from there. However, if the setting does not exist, they each read from their respective application file, i.e. API will read from web.config and web job will read from app.config.